# Changing the Header of more than one bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have seen too many good solutions to change the name of the References heading for the bibliography. But I have more than one bibliography (and more than one .bib file) and I would like to change the headings locally not globally.

I also tried solutions that partition the bibliography (multibib, etc) but these are not working so I prefer to simply change the Heading.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}          
Sample Text.
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{FirstBiB}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{SecondBiB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could do this with biblatex very easily.

Comment: Is there any news here?